# Red circle with vertical yellow line on phone app

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

I have this icon on the phone app.  My phone is not jailbroken, I have no voicemails or missed calls and a reboot did not remove the line.  I appear to be able to make and receive calls just fine too.

Any ideas what it is?

I'm running the latest version of iOS on my iPhone 6 (9.3.3 IIRC).

[image]

Comment: Mine gets the circle [no yellow line] if I'm on a 'low' connection, Edge or GPRS, that can't carry my voicemail. It goes away once I'm back in range of 3G or 4G

Comment: Yeah I read that too, but I'm at full bars and I've had this new symbol for hours...

Comment: Full bars doesn't mean you got 4G, you could have full bars of 'voice only' GPRS

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "full bars and 4G signal according to the bar displayed at the top".  This icon isn't even detailed on Apple's forums, I'm just super curious!

Comment: The latest version of iOS is 9.3.4, not 9.3.3